# Prepared upsert giving unexpected "ambigous column" error

Tags: sql, postgresql, prepared-statement, upsert

I have the following problem: I'm trying to created an "alias" for an UPSERT statement by creating a prepared statement. The statement operates on a table called "Sale" which has the columns (username text, productPid integer, quantity integer, lastTimeBougth timestamp). The primary key is the composite key (username, productPid).

I want this statement to do the following thing: if there is no conflict on the primary key, then insert, else, add the quantity specified in the insert to the quantity specified in the record. This is the code I've written:

```
PREPARE upsert_sale(text, integer, integer, timestamp) AS 
INSERT INTO Sale VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
ON CONFLICT (username, productPid) DO UPDATE
    SET quantity = quantity + $3;
```

However, I get an error saying that the 2nd reference (reading from left to right) to quantity in the last line is ambigous, which I don't get, because it refers to the same exact variable.
I would appreciate some help on this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ambiguous column exception is caused by the second reference to`quantity` in `SET quantity = quantity + $3`. The SQL engine is unable to determine if the column is in the `sale` table or if it is in the virtual `excluded` table that holds the proposed insert rows that conflicted.

The following code should address the ambiguous column issue:

```
PREPARE upsert_sale(text, integer, integer, timestamp) AS
  INSERT INTO Sale (username, productPid, quantity, lastTimeBought)
    VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
  ON CONFLICT (username, productPid) DO UPDATE
    SET quantity = sale.quantity + excluded.quantity;
```

Besides the ambiguous column identifier, there were a couple of other issues. Never insert into a table without explicitly identifying the target columns by name; otherwise, there is a chance that the code might break if the target table's column order has changed. While unlikely, it's still possible.

When possible, only use a positional reference once for each parameter. Doing so facilitates future code maintenance by reducing the number of changes that need to be made if additional parameters are added. In the above, `excluded.quantity` will have the value that was passed as `$3`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the correct and extensive answer.